# How to install h.264 enc using command lines

Tags: 14.04, video, encoding

I am  unable to install h.264 enc using command lines format .could you send me the command lines for installing or another way of installing without using command lines i have tried using sudo commnd nut it is not responding

Comment: Please try this : sudo aptitude install h264enc

Answer (score 1):

Since this package is available in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories, you can directly run the following command to install it.

`sudo apt-get install h264enc`

or

[download the deb from here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/h264enc)

and install.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answer, it is the 14.04 repository, however, it is missing on my 16.04

To quote their sourceforge page

> h264enc is no longer actively developed and is in maintenance mode.
>   This means that only (reported) bugs are fixed and all other
>   development has stopped. Please try out the two scripts below.
>
> h264enc is succeeded by the following scripts: ffx264 and ffhevc.
>
> Official Doom9.org development thread: ffhevc & ffx264 for Linux

So, it would be better to use the [newer package](https://ffx264.teambelgium.net/), based off that.

**Install ffx264**

**This assumes you are working in the directory you downloaded the file to ie Downloads**

Download it from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffx264/
Then extract the file

```
tar -xvzf ffx264-3.2.2.tar.gz
```

Change to it's folder

```
cd ffx264-3.2.2
```

Now build it

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then run the program

```
ffx264
```

[image]

**Install ffhevc**

Download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffhevc/files/latest/download

```
tar -xvzf ffhevc-3.0.6.tar.gz
cd ffhevc-3.0.6
sudo make
sudo make install
ffhevc
```

[image]